# Devise validates_uniqueness fails silently

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

This is my User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :token_authenticatable, :confirmable, :timeoutable, 
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
                 :email_regexp =>  /^([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})$/i

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :name, :confirmed_at, :confirmation_token, :category_ids
    validates_uniqueness_of :email, :case_sensitive => false
    validates_confirmation_of   :password

end
```

When I enter an email address that exists in the DB, my page doesn't re-load and I don't see any error messages or anything.

This is what I see in the log:

```
Started GET "/validators/uniqueness?case_sensitive=false&user%5Bemail%5D=abc%40email.com" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-06-21 03:59:57 -0500
  User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."email" LIKE 'abc@email.com') LIMIT 1


Started GET "/validators/uniqueness?case_sensitive=false&user%5Bemail%5D=abc%40email.com" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-06-21 03:59:57 -0500
  User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."email" LIKE 'abc@email.com') LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to overwrite devise validations? Devise will handle everything.
Logs suggest that you are trying to make some kind of JS form validation, right? If so, try checking for existing user differently:

```
email = params[:email] || ""
@exists = User.where(:email=>email.downcase).count
```

Comment: I am trying to use `client_side_validations` gem, but it never did work fully.

Answer (score 0):

> *"The solution is to perform fully customized validation instead, or to
>   override email validation like you did in your example*"

See

https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations/issues/455#issuecomment-12170527